# Datatable delete emails action with ajax not catching data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Im trying to move from classic loading datatable to server side with the Ajax. Im struggling to 'delete' emails with this code bellow. After the click is not deleting any subscribers or emails. It would be great if anyone can help me with this! I'm trying to use the same logic from before just to load via Ajax. Im not getting any error in the browser.

My application is in Laravel and this is in the controller:

```
public function ajaxDelete(Request $request)
        {
            $data = $request->all();
    
            if (isset($data['ids']) && is_array($data['ids']) && count($data['ids']) > 0) {
                $deleted = null;
                $idCnt = 0;
    
                foreach ($data['ids'] as $id) {
                   $subscriber = Subscriber::find($id);
                   // $subscriber = Subscriber::find($request->input('id'));
    
                    if (!empty($subscriber) && $this->user->canDeleteSubscriber($subscriber)) {
                       $email = $subscriber->email;
                        $subscriber->delete();
                       $deleted = true;
                        $idCnt++;
                                        
                      }  
            
                   }    
               }

           {
            echo 'Data Deleted';
          }         
    
        }
```

This is how I load the button:

```
$deleteButton =  '<a href="#" class="btn btn-coffee btn-small delete-subscriber" id="'.$subscriber['id'].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete</a>';
       $action = $deleteButton;
```

This is the ajax call for delete action in my JS:

```
 $('#table').on('click', '.delete-subscriber', function(){
      var sid = $(this).attr('id');
                      // e.preventDefault();
          // var sid = $(this).prop("id").substr(4);
                    // $(".delete-data").remove();

       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this data?"))
       {
           $.ajax({
               url:"{{ route('subscribers.ajaxdelete')}}",
               mehtod:"post",
               data: {id: sid},
         success: function(response){
               alert("Record deleted.");


                  // alert(data);
                   $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
               }
           })
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
   });
```

This is the route for ajaxdelete function:

```
        Route::get('delete-subscriber', 'SubscriberController@ajaxDelete')->name('subscribers.ajaxdelete');
```

This is my code how was before and Im trying from this logic to change to ajax, maybe this will explain more better.

```
public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        if (isset($data['ids']) && is_array($data['ids']) && count($data['ids']) > 0) {
            $deleted = null;
            $idCnt = 0;

            foreach ($data['ids'] as $id) {
                $subscriber = Subscriber::find($id);

                if (!empty($subscriber) && $this->user->canDeleteSubscriber($subscriber)) {
                    $email = $subscriber->email;
                    $subscriber->delete();
                    $deleted = true;
                    $idCnt++;
                }
            }

            return redirect()->back()->with(['deleted' => $deleted, 'idCnt' => $idCnt, 'ids' => $data['ids']]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

```
JS:

  $(".delete-subscriber").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var sid = $(this).prop("id").substr(4);
                $(".delete-data").remove();

                if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                    $("#delete-form").append('<input class="delete-data" type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="' + sid + '">');
                    $("#delete-form").submit();
                }

                return false;
            });
```

```
<form action="{{ action('SubscriberController@delete') }}" id="delete-form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
```

Comment: You are expecting `ids` in your controller method but you are sending only `id`

Answer (score 0):

you have written ids on your $data index for request parameter in your controller....

```
 if (isset($data['ids']) && is_array($data['ids']) && count($data['ids']) > 0)
```

but it should be $data['id'] everywhere in your controller.

change this if any some issue persist again please mention on comment.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I changed to id but again is not deleting any emails. I posted my previous code which im trying to change to Ajax loading. Maybe will be more clear where is my mistake from the code which worked.